# Manhwa/Manga isekai game gacha about girl with unlimited money

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It started with the girl playing a simple game where she had to mine diamonds of some sorts and she was the first to mine the maximum amount, and by the time she did it the company that created that game was going to launch a RPG/gacha style of game, and suddenly she was transmigrated inside the new game and she was rich. She could use the wallet to take out the diamonds she mined in the other game. And in this world people had to summon/roll for warriors that are humanoid type of flowers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any characters or places?

Comment: I don't remember the site, and neither when I read it. The warriors that fought for the people that summoned all had names that came from flowers (cause they were literally humanoid forms of flowers). I am not sure but one of the warriors was a little girl called Lily (I'm not sure though) She was a common flower considered weak and hence was abandoned by her previous owner until the Female lead found her.

Comment: Just a tip, you can always [edit] and update the details on the post. By editing the post, it will also bump the question, so that other users may notice the update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[Terrarium Adventure](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/terrarium-adventure)*.

> Obsessed with the **clicker game Infinite Diamonds for over a year, Jaehee finally reaches the ultimate in-game achievement** — only to suddenly find herself in the RPG gacha game Terrarium Adventure! Why was she pulled into the game, and how can she get out? For now, she has no choice but to explore!

The "simple game" is a smartphone clicker game; it has an achievement that no one has ever reached to obtain just under 1 quadrillion diamonds. She obtains it right before it shuts down to be replaced with Terrarium Adventure, a new game from the same developer.

[image]

When she obtains it, her reward is a "key", and she's sucked into the world of the new game. In there, her smartphone is considered a wallet, and she can withdraw her obscene number of diamonds to pay for items.

Shortly after arriving she meets a redhead girl named Daisy - I believe this is Lily from the comment. It's revealed she's a Dryad, one of the gacha characters within the game, but the protagonist doesn't realize this at first.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tag `Gacha`.

Comment: Yeeees, thanks a lot. I was feeling very frustrated not being able to remember the name. Thank you so much for helping ❤️ Oh, and next time I forget another manga/manhwa I'll try searching on mangaupdates 